# Diesel in the engine oil

Tags: engine, oil, diesel, skoda

So yesterday my skoda rapid 1,6tdi decided that she has had enough. Basically white/grey smoke started to blow all of a sudden and revving sound, really loud one. Somehow managed to idle all the way to a safe place. Recovery took to a nearest skoda garage. Now they had it overnight and on the next day they telling me that "engine oil overflow by 4ltrs" how the hell this has happened I really cant understand ,as I have serviced my car a year ago, and I do not do any adding to my car myself, only skoda dealers.
They telling me that glow plug has gone too, one of them. 
Now I have looked online and looked for answers in here-apparently it's not overflow, but it looks like diesel in oil.on the day my car broke DPf came on on dashboard, orange color.
Now I believe that is more likely a DPf that caused it. Am I wrong? Please any advice will do, I am going back to garage tmrw, I have screenshot loads of articles, I just need more. I feel like monkeys could do a better job in that garage.

Comment: Before you criticize « monkeys » make sure you know what might have happened... this is a common issue with many diesel engines...

Comment: I think we are not understanding each other, I feel like you insulting me with out reading it properly, but I do apologise if I don't explain myself right. I will repeat that there was not a word about dieseling

Comment: From garage, not a word about dieseling

Comment: It’s called dieseling in some countries and I know it as that as do many mechanics of my acquaintance - that does not mean it is a term common or even used where you are located. I **did** read your post and, based on my experience, felt I gave you a good answer... However, it did not seem to be accepted...

Comment: Yes it has been accepted, goodness me, and I think that's what it is . But garage saying that I over flown engine oil, by 4ltr!

Comment: Perhaps what they said was « the engine has got 4 extra litres in it » not necessarily meaning you poured them in...

Comment: No, thats what they exactly said. I have asked what do they mean by over flow and they answered someone put more oil then they should've, so asked how is this possible if car is always been serviced in skoda dealer, their answer was we don't know.

Comment: Car is only 3 years old, less than 40000 miles on the car. What u saying is right, that's the most logical explanation. And if it wasn't for me searching Internet I wouldn't know what's what. They can't explain to me how oil got there, and why its 4litres over. They telling me its my fault. When someone blaming u for something u haven't done, how would u feel. I will be going back to them tmrw and will show all my findings, and hopefully then they will do something

Comment: There's no way a DPF issue could have caused this - however it's very probably that a this would cause the DPF to fail.

Comment: What do u think have caused this then? I am really getting stressed about it

Answer (score 2):

Diesel getting into the oil is a fault - those « monkeys » are probably correct...

The usual cause is that one or more of the injectors has failed or become faulty and has been leaking excess diesel into the cylinders, washing down the bores and collecting in the sump.

This may need an engine rebuild (expensive) or it may just recover with repair or replacement of the injectors. A set of injectors may not be cheap either...

What happened to your car is not the fault of the garage or those « monkeys » so be nice. This happens sufficiently often and you should have found posts about it happening to several makes of car, it can be called "dieseling"...

Comment: Thank you for replying, but if you read it correctly from the beginning, garage is saying that is " engine over flow" not a word about dieseling. It was my founding though this site that I got logical explanation why has my car broken down.

Comment: If you understand how a diesel engine works then you might, possibly, understand my answer...

Comment: I do not blame garage for what has happened, I blame them for not doing their job properly, instead of coming out with a logical explanation, they just said its overflow, and can't explain that. So please don't assume I am not nice . Yes, I did read here what can cause it, thank to this group. But don't garage should know, or is it a customers job now to search Internet for answers?

Comment: Thank you, yes I do understand, I have read your previous comment in different post about dpf and dieseling.

Comment: Diesel dilution of motor oil was a big problem for GM when they put diesels in cars in the 70's. The general public did not understand that crankcase oil must be changed , especially when "over full".

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough I've had something similar to what Solar Mike suggests... happened with a much older, petrol engined VW Polo. ECU got fritzed by a faulty earth cable, and in the midst of trying to get it going again, before the root cause was spotted, it ended up dumping a good bit of the fuel tank into the inlet manifold, from where it leaked through (petrol - and diesel too - being quite a bit thinner than lubricating oil) the valves and then the piston rings into the oil sump. So then I had to change the oil and top up the petrol tank as well as replacing the earth strap and ECU...

It may not be the exact same cause here, but the otherwise inexplicable overflow, the appearance of what looks like fuel in the oil, the smoke, the sudden revving... sure sounds like what he suggests (an injector that failed by locking open, at least for a short period... they can have quite high flow rates when not operating in their usual intermittent fashion) would be the case.

DPF has almost no way of causing what you describe. The diesel particulate filter is usually a box living somewhere between your catalyser and silencer, i.e. halfway along your exhaust pipe, underneath the passenger cabin, a long way downstream from the engine, designed to catch soot particles in the exhaust. It has absolutely nothing to do with the fuel system or the oil. Perhaps you or other people advising you have become used to calling the general Check Engine / ECU or Sensor Fault light as the "clogged DPF light" as that's the main thing that it tends to come on for, or perhaps it's also lit up because the filter has become clogged (little wonder if the engine was suddenly overfuelling and producing a shedload of rather damp soot), but correlation in this case is certainly not necessarily causation.

I'd suggest getting a better grounding in the theory of your problem before mouthing off at the professionals who didn't cause your problem, might not have been fully briefed on the facts of the matter, and can only call it as they see it, which sounds like, at least from a very basic level, they got mostly right. (I almost wrote "but without getting the correct cause", but it doesn't sound like they even said a cause... they just said the oil level is too high, by four litres, which is quite a lot considering a typical car has about four litres of oil in it under normal circumstances ... unless you drain it out, separate it and examine it, you can't tell straight away that it's oil mixed with diesel fuel, and certainly not if you're just looking at a dipstick covered in some kind of substance coloured mostly by suspended soot particles. And that over-fill alone is enough to cause a lot of trouble, before even figuring out why it happened and how to to prevent a recurrence)